# What is the meaning of the directory specified by '//'?

Tags: bashrc, root-filesystem

What is the meaning of the directory specified by '//'?

It can be accessed by typing in 'cd //' at the comand prompt.

I have tried this on mac 10.9.5 and Centos 6. It shows the contents for the root directory. In the prompt it shows '//' for the directory. Is this simply a glitch in the prompt code? I use \w to show the working directory.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20690872/1870481

Answer (score 0):

cd // = Change the shell working directory to the root directoy

Comment: `cd /` should do the trick as well. No need to double the slash.

Answer (score 0):

Historical compatibility because early versions of Unix used paths such as `//host/path`.

From the bash FAQ:

> E10) Why does `cd //' leave $PWD as`//'?
>
> POSIX.2, in its description of `cd', says that *three* or more leading
>   slashes may be replaced with a single slash when canonicalizing the
>   current working directory.
>
> This is, I presume, for historical compatibility.  Certain versions of
>   Unix, and early network file systems, used paths of the form
>   //hostname/path to access `path' on server`hostname'.